# How to do per-element comparison and do different operation according to result

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I'm using OpenCV in C++ and I'm stuck on a point. I need to do the following:

```
if(src(I) < aNumber)
     do operation1
else
     do operation2
```

For loop takes 100+ ms for 1000x750 image. I don't want to use a `for` loop because it takes a lot of time. I want to use an (some) OpenCV function(s) with that function I could be able to edit some of the values in the matrix. For example, my array is

```
[1 4 5;
 4 6 2;
 3 2 1]
```

I want:

```
if(an element of mat < 4)
    pow(element,2)
else
    element--;
```

According to this `if-else`

```
[1 3 4;
 3 5 4
 9 4 1]
```

is going to be my result matrix.

Does anybody know any functions to handle this except using two `for` loops?

Comment: Are you trying to optimise your code? what "for loop"?, you should post a larger snippet of code to show what src() and I are and also to show the for loop.... and then... ask a specific question :)

Comment: In general with vectorised operations, you will need to do both operations and then merge the results according to the value of `src(I)` (using bit-wise operations). I don't know `opencv`, but there may be methods supporting this more explicitly.

Comment: I have editted the question. Sorry for initial question-ish thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out [compare](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare).  Example:

```
//Mat mask; compare(src, 10.0, mask, CMP_LT);
Mat mask = src < 10.0;
```

Depending on the actual operation you wish to preform you may be able to use the result from compare, otherwise you could take a look at the [gpu module](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/introduction.html).  In particular, the [Per-element Operations](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/per_element_operations.html).

Personally, I feel that OpenCV should be treated a bit like MATLAB, avoid loops, use matrices, and try to use the built-in functions whenever possible (even if they are just implemented as a loop it saves you typing out the same thing again and again).

**EDIT:** Following is an example piece of code to achieve the task in your updated question using loops and using the built-in matrix operators:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
//#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>
using namespace cv;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Load Image
    Mat matImage = imread("Test.png");

    // Convert to Grayscale
    Mat matGray(matImage.rows, matImage.cols, CV_8UC1);
    cvtColor(matImage, matGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    double time, dThreshold = 50.0;
    //int TIMES = 1000;

    //namedWindow("Display", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    //char chKey;

    //imshow("Display", matGray);
    //chKey = '\0'; while (chKey != '') chKey = waitKey(0);

    //----------------------------- Loop Method -------------------------------

    time = (double) getTickCount();

    //for (int k = 0; k < TIMES; k++)
    //{
        Mat matLoop = matGray.clone();

        for (int i = 0; i < matLoop.rows; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matLoop.cols; ++j)
            {
                uchar& unValue = matLoop.at<uchar>(i, j);
                if (unValue < dThreshold)
                    unValue = pow(unValue, 2);
                else
                    unValue--;
            }
        }
    //}

    time = 1000*((double)getTickCount() - time)/getTickFrequency();
    //time /= TIMES;
    cout << "Loop Method Time: " << time << " milliseconds." << endl;

    //imshow("Display", matLoop);
    //chKey = '\0'; while (chKey != '') chKey = waitKey(0);

    //---------------------------- Matrix Method ------------------------------

    time = (double) getTickCount();

    //for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
    //{
        Mat matMask, matMatrix;

        matMask = matGray < dThreshold;
        bitwise_and(matGray, matMask, matMatrix);
        pow(matMatrix, 2.0, matMatrix);
        subtract(matGray, 1.0, matMatrix, ~matMask);
    //}

    time = 1000*((double)getTickCount() - time)/getTickFrequency();
    //time /= TIMES;
    cout << "Matrix Method Time: " << time << " milliseconds." << endl;

    //imshow("Display", matMatrix);
    //chKey = '\0'; while (chKey != '') chKey = waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

As well as reducing the number of lines of code you need to type from 12 to 5, the matrix method is also faster.  Enabling the timing loops (with `TIMES = 1000;`), I get the following times for a medium sized image:

```
Loop Method Time: 9.19669 milliseconds.
Matrix Method Time: 2.82657 milliseconds.
```

With the gpu module I am sure that you could reduce the second time further, but unfortunately I don't currently have a suitable graphics card attached to my current system.

Comment: I have already checked compare but it equalize some values to 255. If I coud find a way to use it, it would be really fine. Also, could I use gpu module directly or should I install CUDA or some other libraries?

Comment: @smttsp I have updated my answer with an example using `compare` to create a mask.

Comment: Thank a lot. This is what I need. Two more question: What is the size of the image? and Could you direct me about how I can use gpu module? For example, instead of `add(...)` function, would my code be faster if I write `gpu::add(...)` or should I do some more thing. Note: I read opencv gpu intoduction

Comment: The image size was 960x540 (large, medium or small depending on how you look at the world).  Code using a GPU can sometimes be faster, take a look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074281/why-opencv-gpu-codes-is-slower-than-cpu) question.  This (http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/webinar/opencv-gtc-express-shalini-gupta.pdf) might also be helpful.