# CUDA not running in OpenCV even after successful build

Tags: opencv, cuda, cmake

I am trying to build OpenCV 2.4.10 on a Win 8.1 machine with CUDA 6.5. I have other third part libraries as well and they have installed successfully. I ram a simple GPU based program and I got this error `No GPU found or the library was compiled without GPU support`. I also ran the sample exe files like `performance_gpu.exe` that were built during the installation and I got the same error. I also had WITH_CUDA flag checked. Following are the flags (related to CUDA) that were set during the CMAKE build.

- WITH_CUDA : Checked
- WITH_CUBLAS : Checked
- WITH_CUFFT : Checked
- CUDA_ARCH_BIN : 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.0 2.1(2.0) 3.0 3.5
- CUDA_ARCH_PTX : 3.0
- CUDA_FAST_MATH : Checked
- CUDA_GENERATION : Auto
- CUDA_HOST_COMPILER : $(VCInstallDir)bin
- CUDA_SPERABLE_COMPILATION : Unchecked
- CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR : C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v6.5

Another thing is that in some posts I have read that along with CUDA the built takes a lot of time. My build takes ~ 3 Hrs where maximum time is taken up during the compilation of `.cu` files. I have not got any errors as far as I know during the compilation of those files.

In some posts I have seen that people talk about a directory names `gpu` inside the `build` directory but I don't see any in mine!

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

What could be the issue? Please help!

**UPDATE:**

I again tried to build opencv and this time before starting the build I added the bin, lib and include directories of CUDA. After the build in `E:\opencv\build\bin\Release` I ran `gpu_perf4au.exe` and I got this output

```
[----------]
[   INFO   ]    Implementation variant: cuda.
[----------]
[----------]
[ GPU INFO ]    Run test suite on GeForce GTX 860M GPU.
[----------]
Time compensation is 0
OpenCV version: 2.4.10
OpenCV VCS version: unknown
Build type: release
Parallel framework: tbb
CPU features: sse sse2 sse3 ssse3 sse4.1 sse4.2 avx avx2
[----------]
[ GPU INFO ]    Run on OS Windows x64.
[----------]
*** CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking) ***

Device count: 1

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 860M"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          6.50 / 6.50
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 2048 MBytes (2147483648 bytes)
  GPU Clock Speed:                               1.02 GHz
  Max Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)             1D=(65536), 2D=(65536,65536), 3
D=(4096,4096,4096)
  Max Layered Texture Size (dim) x layers        1D=(16384) x 2048, 2D=(16384,16
384) x 2048
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    1024 x 1024 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     2147483647 x 65535 x 65535
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and execution:                 Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Concurrent kernel execution:                   Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support enabled:                No
  Device is using TCC driver mode:               No
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
      Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simul
taneously)

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version  = 6.50, CUDA Runtime Ver
sion = 6.50, NumDevs = 1
```

I thought that every thing was fine but after running this program where I had included all opencv and CUDA directories in its property files,

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\gpu\gpu.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

char key;

Mat thresholder (Mat input) {
    gpu::GpuMat dst, src;
    src.upload(input);
    gpu::threshold(src, dst, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    Mat result_host(dst);
    return result_host;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    cvNamedWindow("Camera_Output", 1);
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);

    while (1){
        IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        IplImage* gray_frame = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        cvCvtColor(frame, gray_frame, CV_RGB2GRAY);

        Mat temp(gray_frame);
        Mat thres_temp;
        thres_temp = thresholder(temp);
        //cvShowImage("Camera_Output", frame);   //Show image frames on created window
        imshow("Camera_Output", thres_temp);

        key = cvWaitKey(10);
        if (char(key) == 27){
            break;      //If you hit ESC key loop will break.
        }
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("Camera_Output");
    return 0;
}
```

I got the error:

```
OpenCV Error: No GPU support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in E
mptyFuncTable::mallocPitch, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\openc
v\modules\dynamicuda\include\opencv2/dynamicuda/dynamicuda.hpp, line 126
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @BeRecursive for giving me a lead to solve my issue. The CMAKE build log has three unavailable opencv modules namely `androidcamera`, `dynamicuda` and `viz`. I could not find any information on `dynamicuda` i.e. the module whose unavailability might have caused the error that I mentioned in the question. Instead I searched for `viz` module and checked how is it installed.

After going through some blogs and forums I found out that `viz` module has not been included in the `pre-built` versions of OpenCV. It was recommended to build from source version 2.4.9. I thought to give it a try and I installed it with VS 2013 and CMAKE 3.0.1 but there were many build failures and warnings. Upon further search I found that CMAKE versions 3.0.x aren't recommended for building OpenCV as they are producing many warnings.

At last I decided to switch to VS 2010 and CMAKE 2.8.12.2 and after building the source I got no error and luckily the after adding all executables, libraries and DLLs in the PATH, when I ran my program that I have mentioned above I got no errors but it is running very slowly! So I ran this program:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\gpu\gpu.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat thresholder(Mat input) {
    cout << "Beginning thresholding using GPU" << endl;
    gpu::GpuMat dst, src;
    src.upload(input);
    cout << "upload done ..." << endl;
    gpu::threshold(src, dst, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    Mat result_host(dst);
    cout << "Thresolding complete!" << endl;
    return result_host;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Mat image, gray_image;
    image = imread("desert.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file
    if (!image.data) {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Orignal image loaded ..." << endl;
    cvtColor(image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cout << "Original image converted to Grayscale" << endl;

    Mat thres_image;
    thres_image = thresholder(gray_image);

    namedWindow("Original Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
    namedWindow("Gray Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("GPU Threshed Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Original Image", image);
    imshow("Gray Image", gray_image);
    imshow("GPU Threshed Image", thres_image);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Later I even tested the build on VS 2013 and it also worked.

The GPU based programs are slow due to reasons mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074281/why-opencv-gpu-codes-is-slower-than-cpu).

So three **important** things I want to point out:

- BUILD from source only
- Use a little older version of CMAKE
- Prefer VS 2010 for building the binaries.

**NOTE:**

- This might sound weird but all my first BUILDS failed due to some linker error. So, I don't know whether this is work around or not but try to build `opencv_gpu` before anything and all other modules one by one after that and then build ALL_BUILDS and INSTALL projects.
- When you build this way in DEBUG mode you might get an error iff you are building opencv with Python support i.e. "python27_d.lib" otherwise all projects will be built successfully.

**WEB SOURCES:**

Following are web sources that helped me in solving my problem:

- http://answers.opencv.org/question/32502/opencv-249-viz-module-not-there/
- http://home.eps.hw.ac.uk/~cgb7/opencv/opencv_tutorial.pdf
- http://perso.uclouvain.be/allan.barrea/opencv/opencv.html
- http://eavise.wikispaces.com/Building+OpenCV+yourself+on+Windows+7+x64+with+OpenCV+2.4.5+and+CUDA+5.0
- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/767647/how-do-i-enable-cuda-when-installing-opencv-/

Answer (score 3):

So that is a run time error, being thrown by OpenCV. If you take a look at your CMake log fro your [previous question](http://notepad.cc/qizbisy2), you can see that one of the **Unavailable** packages was **dynamiccuda**, which appears to be what that error is complaining about.

However, I don't have a lot of experience with Windows OpenCV so that could be a red herring. My gut feeling says that you don't have all the libraries correctly on the path. Have you made sure that you have the CUDA lib/include/bin on the PATH? Have you made sure that you have your OpenCV build lib/include directory on the path. Windows has a very simple linking order that essentially just includes the current directory, anything on the PATH and the main Windows directories. So, I would try making sure everything was correctly on the PATH/that you have copied all the correct libraries into the folder.

A note: this is different from a compiling/linking error because it is at RUNTIME. So setting the compiler paths will not help with runtime linking errors.